# How to rsync a chroot without breaking symlinks?

Tags: rsync, symlink, chroot

I'd like to rsync (backup) a chroot environment from outside the chroot.
For that I first make a lvm snapshot of the chroot volume and then run rsync on that.

The only problem with this approach: Symlinks that inside the chroot are absolute are now pointing to the outer-chroot-system and are of course not matching. Since I would like to use copy-unsafe-links, this leads to a false link resolution.
Is there a way to make rsync resolve symlinks from another directory than the main root or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: so you're trying to copy the file the link points to (`-L`)? or copy the symlink itself (`-l`)?

Comment: Neither, I am doing --copy-unsafe-links as stated above.

Comment: No chance with `rsync`-means. I just played with `-R`, `-l`, `-k`- this does not do what you want. There has to be a chroot-mode for rsync to accomplish what you want. Make a feature-request to the rsync-developers...

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your absolute symlinks with relative ones before doing the rsync.

Comment: Yes, that. This is just one of the ways absolute symlinks cause trouble. The oldie-but-goodie [symlinks](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/utils/file/symlinks-1.2.tar.gz) utility is convenient for that.

Answer (score 2):

Changing all absolute symlinks to relative is definitely a good solution, if it can't be done, a convoluted and inefficient way around it that could work is use `sshfs` that has a `--transform_symlinks` option to do just that.

You'd need to set a separate `ssh` server or a user with a separate configuration in the currently running `sshd` and use a combination of

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

and

```
ChrootDirectory /path/to/jail
```

Now, if you're `--copy-unsafe-link` and thus don't care to preserve symlinks or save space, you could just run rsync chrooted inside the jail (copy a statically linked `rsync` there, run `nscd`, *bind-mount* `/var/run/nscd` and exclude both `/var/run/nscd` and that rsync binary from the sync (you may have to bind-mount `/dev` and/or `proc` as well and use `--one-file-system`))